# Implement Vanta.js module into index.html?

Tags: javascript, module, three.js

I created a three.js background with [Vanta.js](https://www.vantajs.com/?effect=net)

If you use it as intended by the website, you only get minified scripts, which make it hard to implement post processing like DoF and such.
Therefore I want to host the non minified files from [Github](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/tree/master/src).

I got _base.js, helpers.js, three.module.js and vanta.net.js, changed the import paths and implemented it into a blank html. The tutorials I found only cover the basic implementation, none that describes how to host the original source files. I hacked something together which does not spit out error codes, but does not show the Vanta effect either...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> body {overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; } </style>
        <script type="module" src="./js/three/three.module.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="./js/vanta.net.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
        <div id="vanta-bg"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            VANTA.NET({
                el: "#vanta-bg",
                mouseControls: true,
                touchControls: true,
                gyroControls: false,
                minHeight: 200.00,
                minWidth: 200.00,
                scale: 1.00,
                scaleMobile: 1.00,
                color: 0xff8900,
                backgroundColor: 0x001b140b,
                points: 8.00,
                maxDistance: 27.00,
                spacing: 20.00
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## EDIT

As stated below, my importing was off. ES6 changes a lot of stuff, so I wasnt properly implementing the examples I found. This is the correct body part:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px;">
    <div id="vanta-bg" style="height:100vh"></div>
    <script type="module"> 
        import VANTA from './jsm/vanta.net.js';
        VANTA({
            //the options are the same
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Note that I now import Vanta inside of the script tags, in a Javascript way.
Also, due to modularization, I do not need to import the three.module.js in the index.html, but rather inside (every) module that gets imported separately.

Comment: Your own script is not executed because it has a `src` attribute. You need to put it in a separate script tag. E.g: `<script type="module" src="./js/vanta.net.js"></script> <script>/* Your script */</script>`

Comment: Looks like it would make sense, but it didnt change anything. Could you have a look at the updated code? Thank you very much!

Comment: Your script tags are nested. Don't nest them, simply put one after the other https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/XqZ325EN

Comment: I did start with that configuration, but this gives me an error when the object is called in the javascript tag: Uncaught ReferenceError: VANTA is not defined
    at (index):12 (I updated the files on the server)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with using modules in the front-end to give you an answer, but this seems to change things a bit _(it's probably not the right way, though)_: https://pastebin.com/7siLyyAw

Comment: Use 'type="module"' instead of 'type="text/javascript"', got it! I now get a whole bunch of different error messages, but they are referring to actually creating the object. Looks promising! Thanks a lot, never would have found this on my own, but makes sense, as it is the three.module.js I am using. Why would you presume its not the right way? Initial googling didnt make it seem wrong in any way?

Comment: _"Why would you presume its not the right way?"_ I don't know, maybe it is, but I would have thought that using modules would make it possible to avoid using `window`, maybe by using `import` instead. Couldn't find a working solution with `import`, though. But again, I'm not familiar with front-end modules at all

Comment: I can now confidently say that I did have to set the type to "module". This was actually a less in ES6 and not Three.js... If you'd maybe want to put your comment as answer, I would gladly close this. I also updated my inital post. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Boy, its a rabbithole, I tell you! :D